# Save Commands Typed To Use later

Tags: linux, bash, shell, memory

I'm looking for something that is like this:

```
$ startmem
$ command1
$ command2
$ command3
$ endmem
```

Later, I want to call it like this:
`mem`, which executes the commands.
To clear, just use `startmem` again. Is there a way to to this?

Comment: Have you tried [defining a function](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html)?

Comment: I want to be able to use this with multiple sets of commands- that could change frequently so I don't want a function for each.

Comment: Each time you have a set of commands, type `mem() { command1; command2; command3; }` then run them with `mem`. If you have "multiple sets of commands", with your suggested process, how are you going to tell them apart? With the function, you have even less typing than your suggestion.

Comment: I think the idea is that `startmem` is a signal to start "recording" a macro. When `endmem` is run, a function named `mem` would be defined with all the preceding commands as the body.

Comment: A quick but untested solution is to define `startmem` and `endmem` as a  noop `:`. Then define mem as `fc startmem endmem`. Executing `startmem` does nothing but it is added to history. Executing `endmem` does not thing and added to history as well. `fc startmem endmem` will execute the commands from `startmem` up to `endmem`. This should persist across logins as long as history is not turned off.

Comment: @alvits If there are multiple (start|end)mem's in the history, does fc take the most recent one? Also, probably need to remove "ignoredups" from $HISTCONTROL.

Comment: @glennjackman - it takes the most recent one. I'm using Oracle Enterprise Linux 6.6 with bash v 4.1.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
startmem () { eval "mem() { $(sed '/^endmem/Q'); }"; }
```

That will take your input, up to but not including the "endmem" line, and generate a "mem" function.

---

If you want it to persist, then you have no choice but to write it to disk

```
startmem () { sed '/^endmem/Q' > ~/.mem_commands; }
mem ()      { source ~/.mem_commands; }
```

But at this point, why don't you just create `~/bin/mem`, add `~/bin` to your PATH, and just edit the `mem` file when you want to change it.

Comment: This answer makes me uneasy due to the use of eval. But you are typing the commands so if you get shot in the foot you're the one loading bullets into the gun.

Comment: Hmmm... Is there a way that after I log out and log back in, it's stored in memory?

Comment: Just add that to your `.bashrc` file (creating it if necessary).

Comment: well, then the `startmem` function is defined, but my line of functions isn't. I need to 'redo' the memory statement each time by calling `startmem`. I can't just call `mem`